# Messy Integral of polynomial over polynomial

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How do I solve the integral

$$\int \frac{(x^3+6x^2+3x+16)}{(x^3+4x)} dx? $$

This integral gets very messy. Can I get a step by step break down of how to solve it?

Comment: General technique: divide the numerator by the denominator and use partial fractions on the remainder.

Answer (score 4):

Do polynomial long division (I will not do that here) to get
$$
\int \left(\frac{2x-1}{x^2+4}+\frac{4}{x}+1\right)dx \\
2\int\frac{x}{x^2+4}dx-\int\frac{1}{x^2+4}dx+4\int\frac{1}{x}dx+\int dx.
$$
The last two integrals are easy to integrate. The first two integrals need substitutions. For the first integral, use $s=x^2+4$ and $t=\frac{x}{2}$ for the second integral (after factoring out $4$ from the denominator). After integrating, we get 
$$
\ln(s)-\frac{1}{2}\tan^{-1}(t)+4\ln(x)+x+c
$$
for a constant $c$. Replace $s$ and $t$ with your former substitutions.

Answer (score 2):

1) Factor the denominator

2) Polynomial + partial fractions

3) Integrate term by term.